# how to replace the nth character in a string with another [ELIXIR/ ERLANG]

Tags: string, erlang, elixir

How do you perform a String `replace_at` in Elixir or Erlang?

For example given this fixed width file:

```
EmployeeFundMappingID EmployeeID  FundID      IsActive EntryDate               ExitDate                ExitTypeID  DateCreated             CreatedByID DateModified            ModifiedByID ConfirmedBy DateConfirmed           GUID                                     IsPooled DatePooled
1                     1118544     1           1        2009-04-20 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2009-04-20 17:48:12.067 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
2                     1027350     1           1        2008-03-03 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2008-05-04 15:13:30.303 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
3                     1024795     1           1        2008-02-29 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2008-05-04 15:13:30.303 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
4                     1116497     1           1        2009-03-24 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2009-03-24 13:00:15.277 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
5                     1116569     1           1        2009-03-24 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2009-03-24 14:43:08.280 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
6                     1116920     1           1        2009-03-27 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        2014-05-17 08:46:48.020 1           2014-10-30 13:34:47.177 NULL         1           2009-03-27 17:16:35.073 NULL                                     NULL     NULL
```

with col positions at:

`[0, 22, 34, 46, 55, 79, 103, 115, 139, 151, 175, 188, 200, 224, 265, 274]`

How do we replace `\s` with `\t` at each col positions?

I'm effectively trying to convert a `Fixed-Width` file into a `csv`

Comment: Have you tried String.replace/4? It can use regex to replace the spaces with commas.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain, the spaces are at specific locations. How would that work?

Comment: String.replace(data, ~r{ +}, ",")

Comment: @AbhyuditJain Thanks. this works, but it splits on date-time

Comment: I didn't notice the space there. It's going to be a tricky regex to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with reducing the original lines with a set of functions changing respective positions in the string.

```
funs =
  [22, 34, 46, 55, 79, 103, 115, 139, 151, 175, 188, 200, 224, 265, 274]
  |> Enum.map(& &1 - 1)
  |> Enum.map(fn len ->
       fn <<s :: binary-size(len), " ", rest :: binary>> ->
         s <> "\t" <> rest
       end
     end)

input
|> String.trim
|> String.split("\n")
|> Enum.map(fn line ->
     Enum.reduce(funs, line, fn fun, acc -> fun.(acc) end)
   end)
```

That might be done in a more elegant way using generated macros, once per a position, and recursive calls, but reducing on function list looks more straightforward to me here.

---

The advantage of this approach would be that it immediately fails on any inconsistent data, assuring (more or less) that if it passed, the conversion was done properly, unlike all others shorter solutions.

Also it’s drastically faster than any `Regex` solution.

---

Since this is to be applied to 16M rows, here is the probably most performant version, that matches the whole row at once:

```
input
|> String.trim
|> String.split("\n")
|> Enum.map(
     # [22, 34, 46, 55, 79, 103,
     #  115, 139, 151, 175, 188,
     #  200, 224, 265, 274]
     # note: this assumes the listed positions above are 1-based
     fn <<
        c1 :: binary-size(21),
        " ",
        c2 :: binary-size(11),
        " ",
        c3 :: binary-size(11),
        " ",
        c4 :: binary-size(8),
        " ",
        c5 :: binary-size(23),
        " ",
        c6 :: binary-size(23),
        " ",
        c7 :: binary-size(11),
        " ",
        c8 :: binary-size(23),
        " ",
        c9 :: binary-size(11),
        " ",
        c10 :: binary-size(23),
        " ",
        c11 :: binary-size(12),
        " ",
        c12 :: binary-size(11),
        " ",
        c13 :: binary-size(23),
        " ",
        c14 :: binary-size(40),
        " ",
        c15 :: binary-size(8),
        " ",
        c16 :: binary
        >> ->
     c1 <> "\t" <> 
       c2 <> "\t" <> 
       c3 <> "\t" <> 
       c4 <> "\t" <> 
       c5 <> "\t" <> 
       c6 <> "\t" <> 
       c7 <> "\t" <> 
       c8 <> "\t" <> 
       c9 <> "\t" <> 
       c10 <> "\t" <> 
       c11 <> "\t" <> 
       c12 <> "\t" <> 
       c13 <> "\t" <> 
       c14 <> "\t" <> 
       c15 <> "\t" <> 
       c16
   end)
```

Comment: The issue with this is it's not converting it into csv

Comment: @AbhyuditJain excuse me? CSV perfectly accepts `"\t"` as column separators. If you want comma-separation, change `"\t"` in `s <> "\t" <> rest` to whatever you want.

Comment: @mudasobwa hi. Please i'm applying this to a file with over 16M rows ... will this perform well?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the probably most performant version; do a benchmark if you need to know what is better exactly, but I am pretty sure 16M lines should be processed fine with both versions.

Comment: @mudasobwa my initial thinking was that i would need to use File.stream at some point to read in the file line by line, so the size would bot be an issue... then apply the map transform, then write back to a file, line by line. I guess `input` could be a File.stream ... correct?

Comment: Why would not you just try? It could have us a lot of time saved. Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Cool then. Just out of curiosity, would you mind to benchmark the reduce by functions example? I think it should have 8× times more taken, but would really appreciate you to confirm (if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is join the date-time first and then replace all the spaces with commas and then revert the date-time to original format:

```
data
|> String.replace(~r/(-\d+)([\s]{1})(\d+)/, "\\1T\\3")
|> String.replace(~r/ +/, ",")
|> String.replace(~r/(\d)(T)(\d)/, "\\1 \\3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two implementations on a dataset with over 16M rows:

```
  def flat2csv1(src, dst) do
    Logger.info("START")

    t = System.system_time(:millisecond)

    funs =
      [12, 52, 76]
      |> Enum.map(&(&1 - 1))
      |> Enum.map(fn len ->
        fn <<s::binary-size(len), " ", rest::binary>> ->
          s <> "\t" <> rest
        end
      end)

    File.stream!(src)
    |> Enum.map(fn line ->
      Enum.reduce(funs, line, fn fun, acc -> fun.(acc) end)
    end)
    |> write(dst)

    log_elapsed("DONE", t)
  end

  def flat2csv0(src, dst) do
    Logger.info("START")

    t = System.system_time(:millisecond)

    File.stream!(src)
    |> Enum.map(fn <<
                     c1::binary-size(11),
                     " ",
                     c2::binary-size(39),
                     " ",
                     c3::binary-size(23),
                     " ",
                     ce::binary
                   >> ->
      c1 <> "\t" <> c2 <> "\t" <> c3 <> "\t" <> ce
    end)
    |> write(dst)

    log_elapsed("DONE", t)
  end

  defp log_elapsed(s, t) do
    t = System.system_time(:millisecond) - t
    Logger.debug("#{s}: #{t} ms")
  end

  defp write(s, dst) do
    File.write!(dst, s, [:append])
  end
```

Results

```
# flat2csv0
11:40:25.055 [info] START
11:42:26.028 [info] DONE: 120969 ms

# flat2csv1
11:45:17.521 [info] START
11:48:25.433 [info] DONE: 187906 ms
```

Comment: Wow. I always respected Erlang VM binary pattern match optimizations but I could not imagine they are _as_ incredibly great.—Thank you!